# IQueryable with Linq expression resulting in NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

The following function results in a NullReferenceException because it is referencing `m.tags`, which has not been declared in the JSON object. This is intentional. I need to query for all JSON objects that have no existing `tags` object.

**SelectNext**

```
TweetModel tweet = client
    .CreateDocumentQuery<TweetModel>( UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( databaseName, collectionName), queryOptions )
    .Where( m => m.tags == null )
    .ToList()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Example Document**

```
{
  "timestamp": "2017-07-05T19:31:18.918Z",
  "topic": "Trump",
  "score": "1",
  "sentiment": "positive",
  "text": "@gjacquette @travi44 @WSJ Where did I say trump shouldn't hire a lawyer? I said the fact his lawyers are hiring law… ",
  "id": "882683325495816192",
  "retweet_count": 0,
  "time_zone": null,
  "lang": "en",
  "screen_name": "bernielove1969"
}
```

Declaring empty values for the `tags` object solves the exception, so I am certain that this is the problem, I'm just not sure how to fix it.

I have tried modifying `m => m.tags == null` to `!(m => m.tags != null)` with no luck as well as a variety of other solutions throughout the last couple of hours. Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Tip: you don't need to use `ToList()` or `Where()` - you can simply do `.FirstOrDefault( m => m?.tags == null )`.

Comment: Since you would always have tags property on TweetModel and I assume it is a string, it would seem to me the serializer is returning nulls so that means m is null  so.... .Where( m => m != null && m.tags == null )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
.Where(m => m.tags == null)
```

to this:

```
.Where(m => m?.tags == null)
```

With the use of the [Null-conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators), you will not hit a `NullReferenceException` if `m` doesn't refer to an object.

---

**Update**

When dealing with `IQueryable<T>` queries, the lambda expressions are converted into expression trees and expression trees don't support the null conditional operator. therefore you can do `.Where(m => m != null && m.tags == null)` instead.

Comment: This would definitely be ideal, but I've had no luck with this solution so far. Your suggestion results in the following: 'An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.'

Comment: @adam.barings My bad, when dealing with `IQueryable<T>` queries,  the lambda expressions are converted into expression trees and expression trees don't support the null conditional operator. therefore you can do `.Where(m => m != null && m.tags == null )` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I figured I'd throw it out in case it helps.  It sounds like it's not an issue of m.tag being null, but that m is a dynamically created object that may not have a tag property at all.  It's not that it's null/not-null, it's that it may not even be there in the object as a property or as a field.

Have you tried looking at something like:

```
m.GetType().GetField("tag") == null  // or...
m.GetType().GetProperty("tag") == null
```

... just something to try.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately, neither are supported.